# How to generate Red, Green and Blue channels individually from a Colour image in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab

I am getting a grayscale image instead of red, green and blue image respectively. Please help in getting the correct output. Suppose i use image name as '2.jpg'.

This is my code:

```
i=imread('2.jpg');
[x y z]=size(i);
for x1=1:x;
    for y1=1:y;
        red(x1,y1)=i(x1,y1,1);
        green(x1,y1)=i(x1,y1,2);
        blue(x1,y1)=i(x1,y1,3);
    end;
end;
figure;imshow(red);
figure;imshow(green);
figure;imshow(blue)
```

Comment: Instead of looping, you could get the red channel as `red = i(:,:,1)` and likewise for the B and G channel.

Comment: This has to be the least informative MATLAB question title, ever.  Consider changing it to something like "How to generate separate red/green/blue images from color image".  I'd even give it an upvote if it were more descriptive.

Comment: @Daniel - I've stopped working on Digital Image Processing using MATLAB and this question was asked quite a long time ago.(I don't remember this)- Someone experienced in this subject will have to specify that a particular answer in this thread is the solution to the problem. Kindly, follow the most upvoted answer in this thread.

Answer (score 3):

Your "red" matrix is a nxm matrix, which is per definition a grey-scale image. If you want "red" to be a coloured image with only red colour, you must fill the other channels with zeros and make a nxmx3 matrix of it.

```
img=imread('2.jpg');
%Preallocate variables with zeros
red=zeros(size(img));
green=red;
blue=red;
%fill one channel with data
red(:,:,1)=img(:,:,1)
green(:,:,2)=img(:,:,2)
blue(:,:,3)=img(:,:,3)
```

Comment: Good answer.  You are generally right about 2D meaning grayscale, but don't forget indexed (colormapped) images, such as from `[imgInds,cmap]=imread('indexedExample.gif');`